# App works in debug mode, but crashes when downloading from Play Store

Tags: android, debugging

So my app works perfectly in debug mode, however, when I download it from the play store, it crashes upon trying to open.  Can anyone help get a logical or stack trace so I can fix the issue?  Thanks!

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Boom!  That helped, I had some filters in my logcat that was preventing me from seeing it.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also, careful when using Reflection and Pro-guard. Proguard obfuscates your code, so class / method names are shortened in release versions.
You can build a release and email the apk to your device for testing before uploading to Google Play, you can also upload the APK as a beta for testing before pushing live.

Comment: This might be a really silly question, but what is Reflection?